# How to automatically add OUTPUT clauses to sql query programmatically

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have some SQL queries which i want to edit automatically with a C# batch to add them OUTPUT clauses, so I can get added/deleted lines for every operation (INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE). The problem is, the target table must be either a dynamic table which I create with an EXEC (in that case I can't get the table after the EXEC is finished) or a static table in which i concatenate all the columns from the source table (but I didn't find how to concatenate all columns in SQL server 2008 R2).

I've been looking for a solution for a very long time, unsuccessfully, even though what I'm trying to do looks simple...
Sorry for my average english and for my potential lack of basic knowledge, I hope you can help me.

Comment: If you can generate code, just generate the target table as a table variable. No need for exec.

Comment: I need the exec to get the source table's schema, because when I use something like SELECT TOP 0 * INTO #TMP_TABLE FROM SOURCE_TABLE WHERE 0=1, the identity column prevents me from inserting rows.

Comment: Can you query the table's schema from C# and generate appropriate code? To get rid of the IDENTITY property (which is a hideous SQL Server design wart) list the columns and say `ID + 0 AS ID` instead of `ID`. Or, use IDENTITY_INSERT.